# creating a Json object with arrays structure

Tags: javascript, json

I want to create a Json object which has an array through javascript when a function is been called. (for example "list()"). And the function should return a json object for the following.

```
{
"config": [
           {
            "name":"steve",
            "id":"123"
           },
           {
            "name":"adam",
            "id":"124"
           },
           {
            "name":"eve",
            "id":"125"
           }
          ]
}
```

Thank you ...

Comment: You want a json obj that contain array? as we know in JS objects can be looked as associative arrays: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html so I wonder if it's not helping you here...

Comment: when you say "json object" do you refer to json string or to actual object containing data? because json stands for javascript object notation and describes a way to serialize basic javascript objects into string. which implies that any javascript object **is** json object..

Comment: "There's no such thing as a ['JSON Object'](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)."

Answer (score 0):

i know that "google the question" answers are not appreciated here but seriously

how hard is it to type "javascript json" into google? and follow the very first link? here: http://www.json.org/js.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for

```
var yourArray = [
           {
            "name":"steve",
            "id":"123"
           },
           {
            "name":"adam",
            "id":"124"
           },
           {
            "name":"eve",
            "id":"125"
           }
          ];
```

[JSON lib](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
```

[JQuery json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/)

```
var encoded = $.toJSON( yourArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

Json is simply the string representation for the object. The whole point of Json is that the syntax itself is valid javascript which can be parsed as an object.

It's hard to understand what you're asking here. If you just want to know how to work with the object from code you can just do something like this:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.config = [];
myObj.config[0] = {};
myObj.config[0].name = "steve";
myObj.config[0].id = "123";
myObj.config[1] = {};
myObj.config[1].name = "adam";
myObj.config[1].id = "124";
myObj.config[2] = {};
myObj.config[2].name = "eve";
myObj.config[2].id = "125";
```

This is exactly equivalent to this:

```
var myObj = {
    "config": [
       {
        "name":"steve",
        "id":"123"
       },
       {
        "name":"adam",
        "id":"124"
       },
       {
        "name":"eve",
        "id":"125"
       }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done complete bin to parse json object from array json string and shows on html format using jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="jsonobj">
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Run" id="btnrun"/>
<input type="button" value="Reset" id="btnreset"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
.jsonobj{
  background:#ddd;
}
.jsonobj .key{
  display:inline-block;
  clear:both;
  color:#993322;
}
.jsonobj .val{
  color:#336622;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:7px;
}
input[type=button]{
  border:1px solid #333;
}
input[type=button]:hover{
  background:#eee;
}
```

JQuery:

```
function list(a) {
    if (a == null || typeof(a) == "undefined") return false;

    return JSON.parse(a);
}
$(function() {

    $("#btnrun").click(function() {
        var jsonarr = '{"config": [{ "name":"steve", "id":"123"}, {  "name":"adam", "id":"124"},{"name":"eve","id":"125"}]}';

        //Convert into JSON Object
        var jsonObject = list(jsonarr);

        var i = 0,
            html = '';
        $.each(jsonObject.config, function(k, val) {
            html += "<div class='key'>Name:</div><div class='val'>" + val.name + "</div>";
            html += "<br/><div class='key'>Id:</div><div class='val'>" + val.id + "</div><br/>";

        });
        if (html != '') {
            $(".jsonobj").css({
                'padding': '5px',
                'border': '1px solid #222'
            });
            $(".jsonobj").html(html);
        }
    });

    $("#btnreset").click(function() {
        $(".jsonobj").css({
            'padding': '0px',
            'border': '0px'
        });
        $(".jsonobj").html("");
    });

    //Trigger Run on ready
    $("#btnrun").trigger('click');
});
```

TRY it on http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpai